# Why must I use "following" instead of "next" when introducing a list?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference, lists

Why is it correct to say:

> We would like to thank the **following** contributors:
>
> - Mr. X
> - Mrs. Y
> - Mr. Z

while it is NOT correct to say:

> We would like to thank the **next** contributors:
>
> - Mr. X
> - Mrs. Y
> - Mr. Z

I see how the word "[following](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/following)" makes sense:

> coming next; listed or shown next

but I don't see why "[next](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/next)" is a bad choice, especially as it's part of the definition above:

> coming after this one;  in the time or place that follows or comes directly after someone or something : after this

I saw [this answer on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/204298/115786) which just says "'following' is generally used," and the question was closed as answerable by commonly available references, but I don't see this answered in those references (maybe I'm just missing it).

Is there any source, rule, or more general way to intuitively understand this?

Comment: If you say *"next"*, it implies that there was also a *"previous"*.  You can say *"I would like to introduce our next guest"*, but only if he's not the first guest. So you could say *"The next contributors we would like to thank are Mr. X, Mrs Y, Mr. Z"* if you've already thanked Ms. T, Mr. U, Miss V, and Mr. W.

Comment: You actually have the answer in your post: next means "coming after this one".  But in your example about thanking contributors, you haven't named any yet, so you can't say there's a "next one".

Answer (score 7):

If you say "next", it implies that there was also a "previous". You can't start a list with "next".

You can say

> I would like to introduce our next guest,

but only if he's not the first guest.

So you could say

> The next contributors we would like to thank are Mr. X, Mrs Y, Mr. Z,

if you've already thanked Ms. T, Mr. U, Miss V, and Mr. W.