# the meaning of "following" in "I would like to introduce our following guest."

Tags: meaning, difference

[stackexchange.com](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/97537/82229):
**(1)** *I would like to introduce our **next** guest*. — I know I can only say so if there was a previous guest before, i.e. the guest I would like to introduce now is not very first.

---

my variant:
**(2)** *I would like to introduce our **following** guest*. — in order to understand this sentence, I have some questions:

Is (2) correct if the guest is **first**?
How would you describe your perception of "following" in this case?

Is (2) correct if the guest is **not first**?
How would you describe your perception of "following" in this case?

Comment: For some reason "our next guest" sounds correct to me,  and "the following guest" sounds OK, but "our following guest" sounds wrong.  I will have to think about that some more.

Answer (score 2):

The first guest doesn't *follow* anyone, so (2) would not be correct!

*Following* isn't really idiomatic for the second and subsequent guests either. We normally use *the following* to introduce a list of things we are about to mention.

> I am doing this for the following reasons...

Comment: If we add "_this is our first guest_", I mean: "_This is our first guest. And now I would like to introduce our following guest_." - now "_following guest_" is perceived to be in relation to "_first guest_", therefore it's correct. Am I right? Thanks.

Comment: As I said, it's not idiomatic; it would be much more natural to use _next_.